# Linux group by, sum and count

Tags: linux, bash, shell

From a directory listing, I have created an output that presents file size in column 1 and a section of the filename (it's a date) in column 2.

```
178694671 2017-10-14
175332227 2017-10-14
175021608 2017-10-14
174851281 2017-10-14
175316643 2017-10-14
```

What I now need to do is group by, sum and count on this list. Group by and count files by column 2, and sum the file size associated with each grouping.

The result of the above output would look like this:

```
879216430 2017-10-14 5
```

I tried this

```
awk '{sum[$1]+= $2;}END{for (date in sum){print sum[date], date;}}'
```

But it provides strange results and I don't really understand what it's doing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is your code? Could you please show what yo have tried so far?

Comment: `awk '{sum[$1]+= $2;}END{for (date in sum){print sum[date], date;}}'` I tried this but it gives a very strange output. I think it might be because the data isn't actually split into columns, merely seperated with a space? Also this wouldn't do the count, only the grouping and sum of file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another associated array to store frequency of date as in:

```
awk '{++freq[$2]; sum[$2]+=$1}
END{for (date in sum) print sum[date], date, freq[date]}' file

879216430 2017-10-14 5
```

Also note key of your array would be `$2` i.e. date not `$1`